# Ionic serve command get stuck in " [react-scripts] Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results..."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I am trying to use the CLI to create a project with Ionic and React. I noticed that the bug is in the Typescript checking step.

I've been trying the following things to solve it:

1. Remove the node_modules and the package-lock.json
2. `npm cache clear --force`
3. Downgrade the Typescript version to 3.3.3333 (Most of the users who had the same problem solve it with this)
4. `npm i`
5. `ionic serve`

But it keeps showing me the same prompt `[react-scripts] Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...`

Dependencies:

```
"@capacitor/core": "2.1.0",
"@ionic/react": "^5.0.7",
"@ionic/react-router": "^5.0.7",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^8.0.3",
"@types/jest": "^24.0.25",
"@types/node": "^12.12.24",
"@types/react": "^16.9.17",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
"@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
"ionicons": "^5.0.0",
"react": "^16.13.0",
"react-dom": "^16.13.0",
"react-router": "^5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
"typescript": "3.3.3333"
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade to react-scripts 3.4.0

```
npm uninstall react-scripts -S
npm i react-scripts@3.4.0

ionic serve
```

Answer (score 1):

**Insights**

If I open a tab with localhost:8100, it works (even the hot reload), but the ionic serve does not open a window by itself and the prompt in the terminal still the same

Comment: Can confirm the same on `react-scripts@3.4.3`. Console output doesn't indicate which port the app is running on, nor is a browser window automatically opened, but the app is indeed running correctly.